# Meteor Template does not output data in each statement

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following three files:

- abc.js
- abc.html
- router.js

The each statement in HTML does not output data if it the HTML is surrounded by template. Removing the template is outputting data.

```
//file name : abc.js

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: [
      { text: "This is task 1" },
      { text: "This is task 2" },
      { text: "This is task 3" }
    ]
  });
}
```

```
//file name router.js

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('mylist',{
    path:'/list',
  });
});
```

```
//file name: abc.html

<template name="mylist">
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</template>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

Why doesn't the template output data with the `#each` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Template.body.helpers` instead of `mylist` helpers.
Try to modify your code as below:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // This code only runs on the client
  Template.mylist.helpers({
    tasks: [
      { text: "This is task 1" },
      { text: "This is task 2" },
      { text: "This is task 3" }
    ]
  });
}
```

You should also remove `<body>` tag from `mylist` template and include your template `mylist` on your html `body`:

```
<body>
{{>mylist}}
</body>

<template name="mylist">

  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>

</template>

<template name="task">
  <li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks GUISSOUMA.. Your answered Helped. :)